# DNS server not working in QEMU usermode networking

Tags: linux, dns, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I am trying to get QEMU 2.8.0 on Windows host to work with my Linux guest with vanilla 2.6.11.12 kernel but it is responding with unknown host.

[image: nslookup]

I am using user mode networking (SLIRP).
Here's my qemu network status:

[image: info network]

And my ifconfig:

[image: eth0]

And my routing table:

[image: routing table]

I am able to ping the router but not the QEMU DNS server:

[image: ping]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you very much.

Comment: There never was a v1.8.0 of QEMU -- did you mean 2.8.0 ?

Comment: @PeterMaydell Yes, that is what I meant. I've update the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not a problem with QEMU but instead a problem with my DNS setup.

My **/etc/nsswitch.conf** contained:

```
hosts: files
```

instead of the correct:

```
hosts: files dns
```

So it was not making the DNS requests to the server.